# Sampling distribution of exponential sample variance (formal not empirical)

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, variance, exponential-distribution

Addressing this problem:

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be iid exp($\theta$) with pdf,
 $f(x)=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$. What is the distribution of the sample variance?

This is to be done by proof, not by simulation/sampling. Everything online says simulation/sampling, so is there no formal mathematics for determining this distribution?

Comment: what is "Xbar - Xbar^2" ? do you mean $\bar{X^2} - \bar{X}^2$?

Comment: The latter would not be sample variance either.

Comment: corrected. just now learning how to type problems in on this thing. new member.

Comment: Sample variance is $\frac1n\sum (X_i-\overline X)^2=\frac1n\sum X_i^2-\overline X^2$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom  $ \frac{1}{n} \sum{X_i^2} = E(X^2) $ and $ \bar{X} = E(X) $. Your equation is the same as mine, except this is a continuous random variable. I need to show the distribution of $$\int_0^\infty (x - \mu)^2f(x) dx = \int_0^\infty x^2 f(x) dx - \mu^2 = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$$.

Comment: @R.Story No. $E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=Var(X)$ is the *population* variance, which in this case is $\theta^2$. Now the edited post makes no sense.