# Sampling Distribution of Exponential Sample Variance (Formal, not Empirical)

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, exponential-distribution, variance

Addressing this problem:

Let X1,...,Xn be independent identically distributed exponential variables with parameter θ, i.e. with pdf, f(x)=(1/θ)*exp(−x/θ). What is the distribution of the sample variance, Xbar - Xbar^2?

This is to be done by proof, not by simulation/sampling. Everything online says simulation/sampling, so is there no formal mathematics for determining this distribution?

Comment: Sure there is, but that's a question for math stackexchage or stats stackexchange.

Comment: Self duplicate: [Sampling distribution of exponential sample variance (formal not empirical)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/450402/sampling-distribution-of-exponential-sample-variance-formal-not-empirical)

Comment: Please don't cross-post. It is against SE policy & wastes a lot of people's time.